# ends-with and namespace-uri in XSTL

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ser="http://service.foo.com" 
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:urn="urn:com.foobar.to" 
  xmlns:wor="http://ffffff.aaa.com:443/AAA/services/Bar">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:submit>
            <urn:question>
               <wor:item>1</wor:item>
            </urn:question>
      </ser:submit>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

expected output:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ser="http://service.foo.com" 
      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:urn="urn:com.foobar.to" 
      xmlns:wor="urn:com.foobar.to">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ser:submit>
                <urn:question>
                   <wor:item>1</wor:item>
                </urn:question>
          </ser:submit>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

this currently is used to match namespace with a specific URI.

```
 <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://ffffff.aaa.com:443/AAA/services/Bar']">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="urn:com.foobar.to">
       <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>
```

I am trying to fix the above to match anything that ends with `/AAA/services/Bar`

I thought by using 2.0 this woudl work but it does not.

```
 <xsl:template match="*[ends-with(namespace-uri(), '/AAA/services/Bar')]">
```

how can i do this in XSTL 1.0 or/and XSTL 2.0?

Thanks

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT you run, result you want and result or error you get when "it does not" "work".

Comment: You have not shown us a minimal but complete XSLT together with the result you want and the one you get.

Comment: @MartinHonnen ah got ya, updated...

Comment: So do you get an error with your second attempt? If so, which one exactly? Or which wrong output do you get? Which XSLT 2 processor exactly do you use? I would ditch the `<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>`, otherwise not even your complete namespace comparison can give the expected output as the serializer has to invent a new namespace prefix for the element in the new namespace.

Comment: currently the xsl:copy-of and my direct comparison is working.  there is no error when i use ends-with, but it does not match the end-width /AAA/services/Bar   .....so I guess the syntax is correct?("*[ends-with(namespace-uri(), '/AAA/services/Bar')]">)

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor do you use, how do you run it? Does it support `ends-with`?

Comment: xalan-2.7.0, and xercesImpl-2.8.0

Comment: Xalan only supports XSLT 1.0, might be that the error in the pattern just lets the processor ignore the template.

Comment: No, Xalan will produce an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="*[ends-with(namespace-uri(), '/AAA/services/Bar')]">
```

will work in XSLT 2.0, as you can see here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NKE

In XSLT 1.0, with no support for the `ends-with()` function, you need to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="*[substring(namespace-uri(), string-length(namespace-uri()) - 16) = '/AAA/services/Bar']">
```

Comment: guess 2.0 is not in my project... where did you get the number 16 from?

Comment: It's the length of the string `/AAA/services/Bar` - 1.